# SAS 9.4 - How to lookup/reference a value from a different dataset without Merge or Proc SQL

Tags: sas

I am currently trying to update an existing error checking code to include a new validation check.

This check is supposed to determine if a postcode is in our master list of valid postcodes (almost 2.7m records) and mark the record as an error if the ID is not on the master list.

The current code is formatted:

```
Data error_check;
set Data;
If (check 1) then error_type1 = 1;
             else error_type1 = 0;
If (check 2) then error_type2 = 1;
             else error_type2 = 0;
run;


Data error no_error;
set error_check;
if error_type1 = 1
or error_type2 = 1
then output error;
else output no_error;
run;
```

My initial thought was to use my go-to Proc SQL IN function to create a new dataset and point the error/no_error subsetting step to that:

```
Proc SQL;
Create table error_check2 as
select *, case when postcode in (select post_code from postcode_list) then 1 else 0 end as error_type3
from error_check
;quit;

Data error no_error;
set error_check2;
if error_type1 = 1
or error_type2 = 1
or error_type3 = 1
then output error;
else output no_error;
run;
```

However, if possible I would like to add the check in as a new line in the error_check dataset for clarity and efficiency purposes (as well as I don't want to be overly dependent on Proc SQL).

I've tried to look up different functions, but haven't found one that seems appropriate yet. This might be because the SAS website is trash and difficult to actually learn new functions from, but I'm not sure where to start.

Thanks

Comment: Create a format out of the postal codes and then use PUT to check if it equals the desired value you map to and otherwise it's not and is an error. https://support.sas.com/resources/papers/proceedings/proceedings/sugi30/001-30.pdf

Comment: You have 2.7 million records in your look up table of valid post codes?

Comment: @Quentin yes, there are about 2.7 million valid UK postcodes, and about 1.8 million active ones. I download it as a csv from https://www.doogal.co.uk/UKPostcodes and it can't be opened or your PC will crash. It takes over an hour to import into sas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an in-memory hash table lookup for this that avoids both merging and SQL. Although you have 2.7 million records, the dataset shouldn't take up too much memory if you limit it to a single column. Here's how you can do it:

```
data want;
    set data;

    if(_N_ = 1) then do;
        dcl hash pcode(dataset: 'postcode_list(keep=post_code 
                                               rename=(post_code = postcode)
                                              )'
                     , hashexp:16);
            pcode.defineKey('postcode');
        pcode.defineDone();
    end;

    error_type1 = (pcode.Check() NE 0);
run;
```

Here's how this works:

- `postcode_list` is loaded into memory as a single-variable hash table called `pcode` where the variable `post_code` renamed to `postcode`
- The hash table's lookup key is `postcode`
- `data` is read line-by-line
- The value of `postcode` in `data` is searched through the hash table for a matching value using the `pcode.Check()` method
- If a value is found, it returns a 0
- If a value is not found, it returns non-zero
- `error_type1` is 1 if a value is not found and 0 if a value is found

Additionally, the hash table will remove duplicate key values by default. Since there are about 41,700 ZIP codes (and about 317,000 ZIP + 4 codes), the hash table should automatically be reduced to one of these sizes if we're only talking about the US. Otherwise, the hash table will be 2.7M records if they're all unique.

Hash tables are very high-performance so this should run quickly for you. I've used hash tables for lookups on hundred-million row datasets and the performance has been quite impressive.

Comment: For lookup validation use `.check()` instead of `.find()`.  Check does not do a data transfer from the hash data object to the data step PDV.

Comment: Thanks, I updated it with your recommendation

Comment: Thanks, this worked - and so fast!
I'd never heard of hash tables before (I've learned SAS on the job so I just pick up what I come across), but this is very useful so I will have to further look into their use.

Comment: Best places to learn about SAS are white papers (www.lexjansen.com) and the free SAS training classes online. If you go through Basic and Advanced you'll learn a ton. Plus, browsing Stack Overflow and the even-more-active SAS Communities programming forums are really great ways to learn. You'll find there isn't a big data problem you can't solve with SAS.

Answer (score 0):

How about the `in` operator with a lookup array?

```
data error_check2;
  set error_check;

  array _code_[99999]$5. _temporary_;
  if _N_=1 then do i=1 by 1 until(eof);
    set postcode_list(keep=post_code) end=eof;
    _code_[i]=post_code;
  end;

  error_type3=(postcode in _code_);
run;
```

Note: I assume the post codes are strings of length 5, or you may want to modify the definition of array `_code_`.

According to this [SAS NOTES](https://support.sas.com/kb/41/182.html#:%7E:text=In%20releases%20of%20SAS%20%C2%AE%20prior%20to%20SAS,the%20array%20to%20easily%20perform%20the%20same%20operation.):

> In releases of SAS® prior to SAS® 9.1, if you wanted to check for the
> existence of a value within an element of an array, you needed to use
> an iterative DO loop to cycle through each element of the array.
>
> Beginning with SAS 9.1, you can use the IN operator with only the name
> of the array to easily perform the same operation.